# Is this shell script for copying files sensible, readable?

Tags: bash

As an exercise in learning bash, I wrote this script designed to automate the process of populating a drive with uncompressed .aiff files copied directly from a CD. It saves me having to do a bunch of separate commands to create subdirectories, check before clobbering, etc.

It stores them in this fashion:

Root directory -> Artist -> Album -> Disc in the series (if necessary)

I wrote it to be run in bash on a Mac. Hence the "open" command.

1. What best practices am I ignoring?
2. Is any of the logic unnecessarily complex? (Aside from the whole endeavor, which I suppose I could just do through the GUI... but where's the fun in that?)

Specifically, I wonder about comparing the contents of an origin directory to a destination directory by outputting the destination's content to a text file and running an inverse grep search on it:

```
for trackname in $(ls -1 /Volumes/$the_disc | grep -vf ~/.harvest/existing); do
```

Thanks for any feedback you can offer this newbie.

```
#!/bin/bash

# > harvest.sh <
# Identifies audio CDs and copies their contents to my archive directory
# Written by parisminton for Concrete Daydreams.
# <parisminton@da.ydrea.ms>

vrs='v 0.7'
lastchange='8/15/11'

echo -e "\n--> Harvest $vrs $lastchange <--"

# ...change IFS to newline...
OLD_IFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'

i=0

tryagain="--> I can't find any more external volumes. Are you sure you inserted a CD or external drive?\n"

function y_or_n () {
  until [ "$pick" == "y" -o "$pick" == "n" ]; do
    echo -e "--> (Enter \"y\" or \"n\".)\n"
    read pick
  done
}

function collect () {
  the_disc=$1
  multi=null
  ls /Volumes/$1
  echo -e "\n--> What's the artist's name?\n"
  read artist
  echo -e "\n--> OK. We're storing music from $artist."

  echo -e "\n--> Is \"$1\" the name of the album?"
  pick=null
  y_or_n

  if [ "$pick" == "y" ]; then
    echo -e "\n--> Excellent. $1 is the name of the album by $artist.\n"
    album=$1
  else
    echo -e "\n--> What's the name of the album?\n"
    read album
    echo -e "\n--> Excellent. $album is the name of the album by $artist."
  fi

  echo -e "\n--> Is \"$album\" a multi-disc set?"
  pick=null
  y_or_n

  if [ "$pick" == "y" ]; then
    echo -e "\n--> Which disc is this? (\"1,\" \"Disc 1,\" \"The Love Below,\" \"etc...)\n"
    read multi
    if [[ "$multi" =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]]; then
      multi="Disc $multi"
    fi
  fi
}

function archive () {
  musicpath="/path/to/music/directory/"

  if [ ! -e "$musicpath/$artist" ]; then 
    mkdir "$musicpath/$artist"
    echo -e "\n--> I just created a folder named \"$artist.\""
  else
    echo -e "\n--> $artist already has a folder in the archive."
  fi
  cd "$musicpath/$artist"

  if [ ! -e "$musicpath/$artist/$album" ]; then
    mkdir "$musicpath/$artist/$album"
    echo -e "\n--> I just created a folder named \"$album.\""
  else
    echo -e "\n--> The album \"$album\" already has a folder in the archive."
  fi
  cd "$musicpath/$artist/$album"

  if [ "$multi" != null ]; then
    if [ ! -e "$musicpath/$artist/$album/$multi" ]; then
      mkdir "$musicpath/$artist/$album/$multi"
      echo -e "\n--> I just created a folder named \"$multi.\""
    else
      echo -e "\n--> \"$multi\" already has a folder in the archive."
    fi
    cd "$musicpath/$artist/$album/$multi"
  fi

  mkdir ~/.harvest
  ls -1 . > ~/.harvest/existing
  tracktotal=$(ls -1 /Volumes/$the_disc | grep -cvf ~/.harvest/existing)

  if [ $tracktotal -gt 0 ]; then
    open .
    trackcount=0
    for trackname in $(ls -1 /Volumes/$the_disc | grep -vf ~/.harvest/existing); do
      trackcount=$(($trackcount+1))
      echo -e "\n--> Copying \"$trackname.\" This may take a minute or two..."
      cp "/Volumes/$the_disc/$trackname" .
    done
    echo -e "\n--> Finished copying."
    echo -e "\n--> $tracktotal tracks from the album \"$album\" by $artist have been saved to $(pwd)."
  else
    echo -e "\n--> Nothing copied. All the files on $album have already been archived.\n"
  fi

  rm -PR ~/.harvest
}

# ...compare the /Volumes list to the pre-defined list of internal volumes
# we know aren\'t the audio CD; any inverse matches are likely to be the
# CD we want to archive...
if [ "$(ls -1 /Volumes | grep -vf ~/.int_vols)" ]; then

  for filename in $(ls -1 /Volumes | grep -vf ~/.int_vols); do
    if [ -d "/Volumes/$filename" ]; then
      fn[$i]=$filename
      i=$(($i+1))
    fi
  done

  if [ ${#fn[*]} -gt 1 ]; then
    echo -e "\n--> I see more than one volume that might contain the music you want to archive:\n"

    PS3="--> Which one do you want? (Type the number of your choice.) "

    select disc in ${fn[*]}; do
      echo -e "\n--> Cool. You selected $disc.\n"
      break
    done

    collect $disc
    archive

  else
    echo "\n--> Does the volume named \"${fn[0]}\" contain the music you want to archive?"    
    y_or_n
    if [ "$pick" == "y" ]; then
      collect ${fn[0]}
    else
      echo $tryagain
    fi
  fi

else
  echo $tryagain
fi

# ...restore IFS...
IFS=$OLD_IFS
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some comments:

1. You script does not work if you have spaces in the filenames, but I guess this cannot happen.
2. You do not need to restore IFS as the script will be run in a subprocess, and will not impact parent environment.
3. You could run `ls -1 /Volumes | grep -vf ~/.int_vols` only once, doing a `filenames=$(ls -1 /Volumes | grep -vf ~/.int_vols)` before the `if`.
4. You could save the `-d` tests in the `for` loop by using `find /Volumes -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -d "/" -f 3` instead of `ls -1 /Volumes`.
5. You could save the entire `for` loop doing a `find /Volumes -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d | cut -d "/" -f 3 | paste -s -d " " | read -a f`

The `cut -d "/" -f 3` does not work well if you change `/Volumes` by a directory that is not directly under `/`.  I would use `sed -e s|.*/||` instead, but this introduces a new tool that you might not be familiar with.

For the rest of the script, I do not know the structure of the data, so I cannot tell.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestions. I'm eager to learn sed. I'd heard about how powerful it is but never really had the context for being able to use it before now. The script actually does work with spaces in the filenames. I thought this was because I quoted the variables before they're expanded.